# PHP array_push not the right function, what to use?

Tags: php, arrays

array_push($array, getData()) gives me:

```
Array
(
    [customer] => One
    [itemno] => Yellow Ribbon

)
Array
(
    [customer] => One
    [itemno] => Blue Band
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [customer] => Two
            [itemno] => Red Tape
        )
)
```

But what I want is:

```
Array
(
    [customer] => One
    [itemno] => Yellow Ribbon

)
Array
(
    [customer] => One
    [itemno] => Blue Band
)
Array
(
    [customer] => Two
    [itemno] => Red Tape
)
```

What am I supposed to use?

Comment: what is the code of getData(), its probably cause it, return an array[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using numeric keys in $array, a simple array_merge($array,getData()) should work, because getData() apparently returns a numeric-indexed multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want...

```
$array[] = getData();
```